# ASP.NET MVC assigning User or Group permissions through web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

Our internal MVC application uses Windows authentication and we control access to the web by adding each user to the web.config (shown below). Question is: Can we grant access to a group by adding

```
<security>
<authorization>
<add accessType="Allow" users="eur\johnsmith"/>
</authorization>
</security>
```

Is there anything else we need to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC it's best to add access directly to Action Methods (or Controllers as a whole):

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"eur\johnsmith")]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Shark, but surely we would be hard coding this assignment for each user.. And what if a user is revoked etc.. Surely we need group level control. I would prefer to not assign attributes to the methods..unless this was the preferred way to go. Thanks

Comment: @DrJameson This is group level control.  The `Roles` would also constitute an AD group name.  So a matter of adding and revoking users is as simple as just altering their inclusion in your AD group.